# Error al crear servidor socket con mi ip publica en python

Tags: python-3.9

Hola cómo están? Hace mucho que no pasaba por este lugar. Bueno, directo al punto. Estoy intentando crear un programa para transferir unos archivos de audio (música) de una computadora a un servidor, el cual es mi computadora. Pero tengo que usarlo fuera de mi red, así que coloque mi ip pública en una variable, corrí el archivo del servidor y me lanzó un error. El cual es el siguiente: "sock.bind((host,puerto)) OSError: [WinError 10049] La dirección solicitada no es válida en este contexto"

Acá les dejo el código del servidor:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
import time
def crear_servidor():
    tiempo = time.time()
    nombre_archivo = "recording0.mp4"
    sock = socket.socket()
    host = ''
    puerto = 22
    sock.bind((host,puerto))
    sock.listen(1)
    print("Iniciando servidor para recibir el archivo...")
    while True:
        conn, addr = sock.accept()
        print(f"Conexión aceptada de {addr}")
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        print(f"Servidor recibe {data}")
        with open(nombre_archivo, "rb") as the_file:
            data = the_file.read(1024)
            while data:
                conn.send(data)
                print(f"Recibido {data!r}...")
                data = the_file.read(1024)
        print("Archivo recibido :)")
        conn.close()
        if time.time()-tiempo>18000:
            break
            sock.shutdown(1)
            sock.close()
crear_servidor()
```

Y por si acaso el código del cliente:

```
def enviar_audio():
    SOCK = socket.socket()
    HOST = ''
    PUERTO = 22
    SOCK.connect((HOST,PUERTO))
    SOCK.send(b"Hola desde el cliente\nTe envio el audio")
    filename = "recording0{}.wav"
    with open(filename, "wb") as archivo_de_audio:
        print("Archivo abierto")
        print("Enviando archivo...")
        while True:
            data = SOCK.recv(1024)
            print(f"data={data}")
            if not data:
                break
            archivo_de_audio.write(data)
    print("Archivo enviado :)")
    SOCK.close()
    print("Conexión terminada")
```

Comment: Prueba con un puerto sobre el 1024, para descartar problemas de permisos.

Comment: Intenté con unos cuantos y no. Me sigue saliendo el mismo error. El tema es la dirección ip

Answer (score 0):

Es un problema de permisos. En general, un usuario normal no puede abrir puertas bajo la 1024 por razones de seguridad.

Probé el código en un Linux Mint 20, y arroja el mismo error, pero si hago

```
sudo python servidor.py
```

el servidor queda funcionando y escuchando en la puerta 22.

La práctica recomendada es usar puertas > 1023 para aplicaciones. En este caso, la puerta 22 es usada por el servicio SSH.

Si cambio la puerta por otra (2000, por ejemplo), el código funciona sin necesidad de invocar `sudo`.

Comment: @abulafia. ¿TIenes alguna referencia que te respalde?

Comment: Claro, acaso desconfías? :-) La pregunta proporciona explícitamente el mensaje de error "sock.bind((host,puerto)) OSError: [WinError 10049] La dirección solicitada no es válida en este contexto". El error 10049 es que se produce cuando LA IP no es válida (y no el puerto). Por ejemplo puedes leerlo [aqui](https://www.altn.com/Support/FAQ/FAQResults/?Number=KBA-01387) o en la propia [documentación de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2), código de error `WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL`

Comment: Por otro lado, el hecho de que el OP mencione una "IP pública" me hace pensar que ha obtenido ésta con algún servicio como [what is my ip](https://www.whatismyip.com/) sin saber que en realidad está obteniendo así la IP del router en lugar de la de su PC, el cual tendrá (según mi hipótesis) una IP local del tipo 192.x.x.x o 10.x.x.x, causando así el error mencionado

Comment: @abulafia. No creo que el OP esté cualificado para hablar de redes. La manera de resolver esto es reproduciendo el problema. ¿Puedes crear un escenario en donde cambiar la IP de cuenta de la diferencia?

Answer (score 0):

El código que muestras contiene:

```py
host = ''
```

lo cual significa que estás dejando que el operativo asigne al socket la IP 0.0.0.0, que representa "cualquiera que sea la IP que tenga esta máquina, en cualquiera de sus interfaces".

Esta es una decisión correcta. Los ordenadores pueden tener varios interfaces de red (por ejemplo, uno inalámbrico y otro con cable), y tener una IP diferente en cada uno, incluso estar conectado a diferentes subredes en cada uno de esos interfaces. Si quisieras admitir conexiones **solo desde uno** de ellos, entonces podrías usar `host = "la ip del interfaz"` y en ese caso el socket quedaría ligado a sólo uno de sus interfaces. Los clientes que llegaran por otros interfaces no podrían conectar. Al poner `host = ""` admites conexiones por cualquiera de los interfaces.

### Tu problema

Creo que lo que te ha sucedido es que has intentado hacer `host = "una cierta ip"` y que la IP que has puesto en ese caso no es la de ninguno de los interfaces de la máquina. Mi razón para pensar esto es que has obtenido el error WinError 10049 que sucede precisamente en ese caso.

Lo más recomendable es que dejes `host` como una cadena vacía, tal como lo tienes en el enunciado. Otra recomendación importante es que **no uses el puerto 22** para escuchar, ya que ese puerto está reservado para otro protocolo (en concreto ssh). Es mejor que uses números de puerto por encima del 52000 (y debajo del 65535), que son los que están libres y no tienen asignado ningún significado especial. No obstante el problema de WinError 10049 no está relacionado con el puerto, sino con la IP.

Sospecho que lo que ha ocurrido es que has intentado poner en `host` el valor de la IP pública de tu casa. Pero esa es la IP de tu router y no la de tu equipo. Si usas `ipconfig` verás las IPs de todos los interfaces de red de tu PC y verás que ninguna de ellas es la que tú considerabas como "IP pública". La situación sería por ejemplo la de la siguiente figura:

[image: Ejemplo de red]

La IP de tu servidor pertenece al rango de las IPs "privadas". Estas son IPs que son inaccesibles desde fuera (desde internet). El cliente que aparece a la derecha en la figura no podrá conectar nunca con esa IP (porque de hecho esa misma IP pueden tenerla muchos equipos diferentes en internet, cada uno dentro de una red privada diferente). El cliente que aparece a la izquierda en cambio sí podrá conectar con esa IP por estar en la misma subred (privada) que el servidor.

Cuando cualquier equipo de la red de la izquierda intenta "salir" a internet (abrir una conexión con un equipo que está fuera), ese tráfico ha de pasar por el router. Éste entonces reemplaza la IP que venía en el paquete (que era una IP interna), por la IP externa del router, que es lo que tú considerabas tu "IP pública".

Cualquier servidor de internet que reciba una conexión desde cualquiera de los equipos de tu casa, verá que vienen "de la misma ip" (la del router), y no tiene forma de saber la IP interna original. Cuando el servidor responda, el router redirigirá la respuesta al equipo correcto, pues cuando hizo la conexión al exterior guardó "memoria" de quién la iniciaba.

Este esquema impide no obstante que un equipo externo pueda conectarse a uno de los servidores internos. El equipo externo sólo conoce la IP del router, pero si intenta conectar con esa IP, será con el router con quien estará hablando y no con uno de los equipos internos.

### Solución

La solución a este problema consiste en configurar el router para "abrir un puerto". Cómo se hace esto depende de cada router. En esencia consiste en configurar el router para que escuche en un cierto número de puerto (por ejemplo el 52000) y decirle que cuando alguien intente conectar con él, redirija la conexión hacia una de las máquinas internas y al puerto que le digas.

Por ejemplo, basándonos en la figura, podrías configurar el router y decirle "abre el puerto 52000 y redirige el tráfico hacia 192.168.1.10, puerto 52000".

Entonces el cliente externo se conectaría a la IP del router (80.12.4.3 en el ejemplo), puerto 52000 y de ese modo podría hablar con el servidor interno. En éste no necesitas hacer nada especial en el código. Puedes dejar `host = ""` como expliqué al principio.